# A JFormattedTextField to accept a currency format without decimals

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield, currency-formatting

How do I code a `JFormattedTextField` to accept a currency format without decimals?

I have tried looking for my answer everywhere. Here, Oracle, Google, and Code Ranch to be specific.

My question: How do I code a formatted text field to accept a currency format without decimals. The text field can accept a value anywhere from $5 to $10,000,000. I would like it to include the "," when need. This field will not be used for mathematical expressions so there is no need to convert it from a string.

Here is the code that I am trying to use. This format is not allowing me to enter any digits at all in the formatted text field.

**buildInfo method**

```
//The buildInfo method will build the info panel
private void buildInfo()
{
    info = new JPanel();
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout (3,1);
    info.setLayout (gl);

    //Create panel, label, and text area for pledgers name
    p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    label1 = new JLabel ("Pledger's Name:  ");
    p1.add (label1);
    text1 = new JTextField (20);
    p1.add (text1);

    //Create panel, label, and text area for pledge amount
    p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    label2 = new JLabel ("Pledged Amount: ");
    p2.add (label2);
    NumberFormat amount = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    amount.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    NumberFormatter pAmount = new NumberFormatter(amount);
    pAmount.setMinimum(5.0);
    pAmount.setMaximum(10000000.0);
    pAmount.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    text2 = new JFormattedTextField (pAmount);
    text2.setColumns(12);
    p2.add (text2);

    //Create panel, label, and text area for charity being pledged
    p3 = new JPanel();
    p3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    label3 = new JLabel ("Charity Pledged To:");
    p3.add (label3);
    text3 = new JTextField (20);
    p3.add (text3);

    //Add panels to main panel
    add(p1);
    add(p2);
    add(p3);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);

NumberFormatter formatter = new NumberFormatter(format);
formatter.setMinimum(5.0);
formatter.setMaximum(10000000.0);
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);

JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
field.setValue(5.0);
```

Comment: Don't you need to specify the locale:  `java.util.Currency usd = java.util.Currency.getInstance("USD");` then `format.setCurrency(usd);` ?

Comment: Only if `Locale.US` is not your default `Locale`

Comment: @Reimeus I tried the code you posted and now it will not enter anything in the textfield.

Comment: Set the initial value to "activate" the field. Also allow overwrites will help. See updates

Comment: thank you that worked for the initial value, but now the issue lies within an action listener, that resets the values to null for a new entry. I can get to reset value, but then it does not except input here is the code for the action listener                       'code'                                                         private class NewListener implements ActionListener
     {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent n)
         {
             text1.setText("");
             text2.setValue(0.0);
             text3.setText("");
         }
     }   thoughts?

Comment: Okay, I figured it all out. I had to change my minimum to 1 so it would except all digits, thanks for all the help.